# MySql search to ignore punctuation, symbols and spaces while data in db has special charactors

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search, replace

I have a huge innoDB Table of inventory over 40 million records which keeps on updated using csv files (files over 1 million data each time). We use `Load Data Infile` method for importing data to the table.

The table has a filed named part_number which is the unique identifier for each inventory item. The data in this field contains one or more special characters like '-','_','#','$'," " etc..

eg. Abcd-1234

We have a facility for end user to search on this table using part_number as the keyword. 
There are three types of search 
a) Exact Match
b) Contains With
c) Starts With

My requirement is to show users results with special charactors even if they search without those characters like  '-','_','#','$'," " etc..

eg. A user should be able to search for Abcd1234 and get the result Abcd-1234.
    A user should be able to search for Abcd-1234 and get the result Abcd1234
    A user should be able to search for Abcd_1234 and get the result Abcd1234 and Abcd-1234

Notes: To avoid table lock during insertion and few other dependencies, I'm compelled to keep table as `InnoDB`.

Adding a new column that stores part_number omitting punctuations and run the search towards that field was a solution I thought of, but it would affect the data import process which is not acceptable..

I had tried REGEXP but was not successful to suit my criterion. My criteria is as follows
a) user can search with or without special characters
b) Data in part_number field may or may not contain special character anywhere 
c) We should be able to show the result in any case..

Please let me know if there is a way to solve this issue..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this, it will help you 

`Select REPLACE(cname, '-', '') as cna From country HAVING cna LIKE '%APRE29192%'`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could look into REGEXP and make a regular expression that'd suit your needs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: I had tried REGEXP but was not successful to suit my criterion. My criteria is as follows
a) user can search with or without special characters
b) Data in part_number field may or may not contain special character anywhere

Comment: If you are aren't going to attempt to resolve the specific question asked, then dropping a link the mysql docs as a comment under the question seems more sensible than answering.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions can be to use *MySql TABLE VIEW*, where you can have column with alphanumeric *part_number* tag to search on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(cname, '-', ''), '.', ''), '\'', ''), ' ', '') 
AS cna FROM country HAVING cna LIKE   
CONCAT(CONCAT('%',REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('$search_term', '-', ''), '.', ''), '\'', ''), ' ', '')),'%')
```